# Confusion about context

Tags: python

I'm still quite new to the whole blender python API. One of the thing I struggle with is context. I have a concrete question in mind though: Consider the simple operator below. What's the difference context and bpy.context?

```
class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def execute(self, context):

        context.active_object
        bpy.context.active_object
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Difference is that `context` is already passed to the execute method (comes in by default). This is pretty essential since in blender everything has `context`, recommend try to understand this concept before writing any operators: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_quickstart.html#context

Comment: Yeah. I know that I have been hacking around in my scripts. It works, but it's likely quite unstable. Thanks for the link, I'll definetly give it a look. But isn't bpy.context.active_object the "current" context and hence the same as the one just passed into the operator?

Comment: Just tried to explain it and get the ball rolling, don't take it personal. In other words: `bpy.context` is a *new* reference.

Comment: Oh I didn't take it personal. I just find it a quite confusing. But thinking of bpy.context as a new context and these are then passed to operators really makes sense. Thanks and I kept the ball rolling ;-)

Comment: Could someone tell me, when add new method in the class, should I need to set (context) as arguments?

Comment: AFAIK at the moment, nothing.  Using the argument is good practice. Have not seen where the values differ, but this could change in the future.  For example when overriding context of an operator, the devs _could_ make a change such that the argument is the overridden context and `bpy.context` is the actual context.   A better example is perhaps the `scene` argument of a handler, which is often ignored and `bpy.context.scene` is used instead, which _will work as expected; till it doesn't_  @tokikake No, not necessarily.